# C# listview Sort with a subitem column using a button click

Tags: c#, sorting, listview, buttonclick

I am creating a scheduling algorithms program using c# and in the SJF which I have to re-arrange the processes burst time list (which is a subitem column) in an ascending order , I succeeded rearranging the list using the column header click which is explained how in [this topic by microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx) but I want to use a specific button for this , if I can call the columnclick even in this buttonclick event addressing that subitems column that would be nice but I don't know what exactly to pass in the second argument (which is the header to be clicked of course)

Comment: just pass `(null, null)` to the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh okay I cannot believe I actually solved the problem seconds after posting this , but since I posted it I am answering it so if anyone encounters this , in the topic microsoft they tell you to add this `this.listView1.ColumnClick += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventHandler(this.listView1_ColumnClick);` in the form constructor , do this but add instead of `this.listView1_ColumnClick` `this.Button_click` so it is `this.listView1.ColumnClick += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventHandler(this.button1_Click);` now go to you button_click event and add those lines `this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(yourcolumnheaderindex);
listView1.Sort();` they are supposed to be added in the columnclick event according to MC's topic to execute the sorting functions , I wish this helps who encounter the problem

Comment: For posterity [ListView.ListViewItemSorter](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter?view=netframework-4.7.2) , with using `ListViewItemComparer`